# output when all possibilities have been searched in the search tree in the prolog

Tags: prolog

I have written the following program for verifying if the student specified by the "S" has received the grade "A" in all his subject. Here, I know that I can only give output 'true', when all the paths in search tree has been evaluated with grade 'A'. I am able to achieve if a student has not received grade 'A' by cut predicate. But really not getting how to specify the predicate that it evaluated to true when all paths have been searched.

```
grade(123,'CSE1','A').
grade(123,'DIC','A').
grade(123,'ML','A').
grade(123,'PL','A').
grade(123,'CVIP','A').
grade(1234,'CSE1','A').
grade(1234,'DIC','A').
grade(1234,'ML','A').
grade(1234,'PL','B').
grade(1234,'CVIP','B').

honor(S):-grade(S,_,Y),not(Y='A'),!,false.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would modify the procedure this way (your code it's working for you?)

```
honor(S) :- grade(S,_,_), (grade(S,_,Y), Y \= 'A', !, fail ; true).
```

test:

```
?- honor(S).
S = 123 ;
S = 123 ;
S = 123 ;
S = 123 ;
S = 123 ;
false.

?- setof(S,honor(S),L).
L = [123].
```

*edit* after your comment, I think this snippet could be more useful

```
honor(S) :- once(a_grade(S)).
a_grade(S) :- grade(S,_,_), (grade(S,_,Y), Y \= 'A', !, fail ; true).
```

*more edit* another, better definition, using *all solutions* builtin [setof](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=setof/3)/3:

```
honor(S) :-
   setof(S, C^G^grade(S,C,G), Ss),
   member(S, Ss),
   \+ (grade(S,_,G), G \= 'A').
```

*one more edit* using setof/3 we can avoid to build the entire list, but only that of relevant subjects:

```
honor(S) :-
   setof(S, C^G^(grade(S,C,G), \+ (grade(S,_,G2), G2 \= 'A')), Ss),
   member(S, Ss).
```

Comment: Given a student ID, it should tell only true or false..But the above definition will tell true for each 'A'..

My code is giving correct output only for the student who didn't score 'A' in all his subjects.

Comment: Yes, now it is fine..I was trying to get the results using primitive operations.Do you think is this possible without using once predicate?

Comment: And a small edit from my side:
honor(S) :- once(a_grade(S)).
a_grade(S) :- (grade(S,_,Y), Y \= 'A', !, fail ; true).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of getting the answers for the above question:
1.First using setof as specified by the Capellic.

```
honor(S) :-
   setof(S, C^G^(grade(S,C,G), \+ (grade(S,_,G2), G2 \= 'A')), Ss),
   member(S, Ss).
```

2. Without using setof:

```
ismember(S):-grade(S,_,Y),!.
honor(S) :- ismember(S),\+ (grade(S,_,Y), Y \= 'A').
```